# Maven - Shade Plugin doesn't work when creating Manifests

Tags: maven-3, manifest, maven-shade-plugin

I have tried shading my jar using a custom manifest file and also manifest entries. In both cases, it's not even accepting any manifest file.

I have looked into Apache Maven docs for Shade plugin and it's not working as per the docs.

Here is my Shade Config:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>kafkapub.main.app.MainApp</mainClass>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>launcher</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Has anyone seen similar issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I sorted the issue.

Basically it created the `-shaded` artifacts. And since there were three jars:

`original-*.jar`

`*.jar`

`*-shaded.jar`

It was quite confusing. But I can see everything in the Shaded jar now thanks.